# How can I manually make the scroll manager work, when I have overridden the built in on_touch_down and on_touch_move methods?

Tags: python, kivy

So, I managed to make buttons work in my application by saying that on_touch_down if the x and y are correct(where the button is), then:

```
self.tagasi.dispatch('on_press')
```

'tagasi' being the name of the button.
Now the next obstacle is how can I make scrollview work, since that doesn't appear to be this easy. In order to get kivy to take in touch inputs (I am developing this app for IOS) I have to manually rewrite much of the functionality. Not ideal, but less whining, more work.
So if the button works like this:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.manager.current == "sc2":
        if 0 < touch.y/self.height < 0.2 and touch.x/self.width > 0 and touch.x/self.width < 1:
            self.tagasi.state = "down"
            self.tagasi.dispatch('on_press')
```

What would be the equivalent way of making scrollview work?

My KV looks like this:

```
Screen:
    name: "sc2"

    size: root.width, root.height
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id: tagasi
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom": 0}
            text: "go back"
            on_press:
                manager.current = "sc1"
                manager.transition.direction = "right"


    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        id: kerimine
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: root.width, root.height
            padding: 10, 10
            text:
                'really some amazing text\n' * 100
```

I would like the ScrollView to work, but have no idea how to manually rewrite all the necessary things for that (like I did with the button by manually telling it to `'on_press'`)

Comment: Rather than doing a comparison of the touch position against self.height/width, it would be better to use the `collide_point` method of the child button you want to activate.

Comment: And as for the actual question, don't aim to rewrite, aim to override where necessary. In this case, if you don't want to hijack the touch event to activate your button, that's when you should just call `super().on_touch_down(touch)` to invoke the normal touch handling.